# How to automate batch job creation/processing in sagemaker?

Tags: terraform, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sagemaker

I have created model and other configuration via cloudforamtion ( sample code below) but based on documentation provided here, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_SageMaker.html, i wanted to see if i can create/run/automate batch transform jobs in sagemaker. I have seen examples of create/run jobs via cli or python sdk , but can one create/run jobs via cloudformation or terraform?

```
Type: AWS::SageMaker::Model
Properties: 
  Containers: 
    - ContainerDefinition
  ExecutionRoleArn: role
  InferenceExecutionConfig: 
    InferenceExecutionConfig
  ModelName: 'somemodel'
  PrimaryContainer: 
    ContainerDefinition
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look at creating and invoking a Lambda function via CloudFormation to create the Batch Transform Job using boto3.